# XSLT Unexpected repeated text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating a html page with xslt to format my xml into a html page, however I am getting a value repeated and I can't find why, below are my xsl, xml, and html. I have indicated where my repeat value occurs directly below, Thanks for everyone's help!

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Joys of a MAD man</legend><ol> 
            Joys of a MAD man *********** Why is the title repeated? ************
           <li>Slow Moving<a href="./Music/Splintz - Joys of a MAD Man/Slow Moving.mp3"> 
          [Download]
          </a></li> 
</ol></fieldset>
```

My XML

```
<albums>
    <album>
        <title>Joys of a MAD man</title>
        <track>Slow Moving</track>
    </album>
    <album>
        <title>Single</title>
        <track>None</track>
    </album>
</albums>
```

and finally my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="album">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><xsl:value-of select="title/text()" /></legend>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="track">        
           <li>
               <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
               <a>
                   <xsl:attribute name="href">
                   <xsl:text>./Music/Splintz - Joys of a MAD Man/</xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                   <xsl:text>.mp3</xsl:text>
               </xsl:attribute>
               [Download]
               </a>
           </li>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are [built-in default template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) that copy text to the result document.**

`<xsl:apply-templates/>` is short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>`.

You used `xsl:apply-templates` inside the template match for `album`.  When you are "standing" on the `album` element, `title` is one of the child nodes that get processed.

**The built-in template matched `title` output it's `text()` "Joys of a MAD man" the second time.**

There are a number of ways to prevent the `title` text from being output the second time.  You could:

- add an empty template matching `title` to your stylesheet to prevent the built-in template from matching:

  - `<xsl:template match="title"/>`
- exclude `title` from your `apply-templates`:

  - `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::title)]"/>`
- only apply-templates to the `track` child elements:

  - `<xsl:apply-templates select="track"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Because you apply `<xsl:apply-templates />` to the same context name `album` as you do the `value-of` above. It strips all text nodes from all descendants.
Say explicitly `<xsl:apply-templates match="track" />`.

Comment: Alternatively, add an empty template for the title element: `<xsl:template match="title"/>`

Answer (score 1):

**As pointed out by other people, the default XSLT processing is selecting for execution the built-in XSLT templates** and this results in outputting text nodes.

As your code isn't relying on the XSLT built-in template for a text node, the simplest possible solution is to override this template with one that has no body.

**Add the following to your code**:

```
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**Now your full code becomes this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="album">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <xsl:value-of select="title/text()" />
            </legend>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="track">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:text>./Music/Splintz - Joys of a MAD Man/</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    <xsl:text>.mp3</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute> 
                    [Download]               
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and the result doesn't contain the unwanted repeated text**:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Joys of a MAD man</legend>
   <ol>
      <li>Slow Moving<a href="./Music/Splintz - Joys of a MAD Man/Slow Moving.mp3">
                [Download]
            </a>
      </li>
   </ol>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Single</legend>
   <ol>
      <li>None<a href="./Music/Splintz - Joys of a MAD Man/None.mp3">
                [Download]
            </a>
      </li>
   </ol>
</fieldset>
```